# Javascript - Can I display the value of a cookie in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I have a bootstrap website and I stock user information in cookies with the plugin JS-cookie.

Can I show the value of the cookie in the HTML with classic JS/Jquery or do I have to use a framework like Angular ?

EDIT :

I use js-cookie  https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

So my code is, in the head page :

```
         <script>Cookies.set('money', '200', { expires: 7 });</script>
```

and in the body :

```
       <p> You have  <script>Cookies.get('money')</script> dollars </p>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using a cookie value like any other value that you might use in jQuery?  Did that not work?

Comment: short answer: yes. unwanted answer: yes, but don't. cookies are for your server, and are sent automatically with every single http request. If you're pretending the cookie is a user setting, do your user profile management properly. Use the cookie for login status only, then consult the user database (via an API or whatever) to get the data you actually want to *show* on your site.

Comment: If cookies were only meant for the server there wouldn't be a [client-side API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) for them. Some client-side only apps can use cookies effectively as a semi-persistent storage mechanism. One could also use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In native JavaScript, you can do the following. Note: this doesn't seem to work on Stackoverflow because of a security restriction, but it does seem to work in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/trevorhreed/pen/QyJgqv?editors=1010).

```js
var arr = document.cookie.split(';'),
    cookies = {};
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var parts = arr[i].split('=');
  if(parts.length !== 2) continue;
  cookies[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1];
}
console.dir(cookies)

document.getElementById('out').textContent = cookies['myCookieKey'];
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

**Update**

Using the JS-Cookie code:

```
<p>You have <span id="amount"></span> dollars</p>

<script>
document.getElementById('amount').textContent = Cookies.get('money');
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `innerText`, it's not standard and Firefox doesn't support it. Use `textContent`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't just insert a script in the middle of HTML to get the result of a function. The script has to perform an operation to put a value into the DOM.

```
<p You have <span id="amount"></span> dollars </p>
<script>
var amount = Cookies.get('money');
document.getElementById('amount').textContent = amount;
</script>
```

Comment: So what do I have to put inside my html exactly ?  <script>cookieValue</script> ?

Comment: You just have to put the code inside a `<script>` tag, just like any other Javascript. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @ZerhAriel - that question cannot be answered until you post more code that shows what the cookie name is and what HTML element you want the cookie to be added to.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it using the cookie plugin you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up using the other answer (innerHTML seems to better suits my needs). I would mark your answer good as well if I could.

Comment: You should only use `innerHTML` if the cookie contains HTML markup that you need to render.